# rigid movements are not working after generating rig using rigify addon

Tags: mesh, bones, rigify, rigidbody

[image]

this is my mesh which is in .fbx format

and i have added armature (basic human )

[image]

moved all my bones such that they are inside the mesh

applied scale for mesh

applied scale and location for bones

and selected body mesh along with bones and parented them with automatic wieghts

its fine till here without any errors
and im able to move the mesh when i moved the bone

[image]

[image]

but after generating rigid and when i get into pose mode and try to move something
nothing is being changed

Attached my blender file
please have a look

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pdqwts0n55gk7bt/stacko.blend?dl=0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is step 6 *"and selected body mesh along with bones and parented them with automatic wieghts"*

You parented the mesh to the *metarig*, and then the generated *rig* to the mesh:

- metarig → mesh → rig

**That's wrong. Correct relationship is:**

- rig → mesh

Clear the parent relationship (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) of the mesh and the rigs. The *metarig* is only used to lay out the bone structure. Then you generate the actual *rig* (default name is "rig"). This one is the parent for the mesh (<kbd>P</kbd>, *With Automatic Weights*. The *rig* must be active object = selected last)

**Side notes:**

The layout of the bones of the *metarig* is not ideal and you should adjust the position of some bones:

- the "knee" of the bones don't match the knee of the mesh. Move it higher
- the head bone is too short, it should touch the top of the head
- the hand bones (last ones of the arms) should match the mesh's hands. That is, be inside of the hands.
- the right heel bones (*heel.02.r*) is rotated. It should lay on the ground like the left one. Select the left one and use the menu entry *Armature > Symmetrize* to fix it.
- toe and heel bones should touch the ground and the edges of the mesh
- arms (bones) are not symmetrical

Comment: wheni tried to parent bones to mesh as you said I not getting automatic weights option
instead im getting(object)
i'm confused 
first ill take the bones inside the mesh select it and then parent to the mesh 
and then generate rig 
is it ???

Comment: First, you edit the metarig and place the bones in the mesh. Then in Object mode, generate the rig from the metarig with the *Generate Rig* button. Finally, parent the mesh (child) and the generated rig (parent) *With Automatic Weights*. The rig must be highlighted in orange (in Blender's default theme), the mesh is highlighted in a darker reddish color.  If you chose the wrong order and try to make the rig the child then there is no *With Automatic Weights* option.

Comment: i appreciate your amazingly detailed explanation and i did everything as you mentioned removed parent for mesh and bone. gnerated rig with rigify  and tried to connect mesh to generatd rig(parent) but when i tried to do that im getting error "loop in parents"

Comment: Have you cleared the parent relationship of all 3 objects (metarig, body mesh, generated rig)? The error is because you parented them as shown above. And when you try to parent the "tail" with the "head" of this hierarchy then Blender complains that you try to create a loop. The parent cannot be a child of its own child, you know? Dissolve this hierarchy. You can check the relationship in the outliner and in the *Object Properties* tab,  *Relations* section, *Parent* inputbox.

Comment: thanks  for contributing your knowledge to the community 
it helped me so much :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because your weight paint body is blue all over.

I changed the arm manually by weight painting and then i could move the arm by using the rig.

[image]

Comment: @Chrisi just changed the the wightpaint from blue to other and tried to move still its same 
the mesh isnt moving just the rig part is moving